# SQL cumulative based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to take cumulative based on condition. If it is holiday I dont want to take cumulative.

If the row is the first row in date order and if that day is holiday then it should take daywiseplan value. For all subsequent rows, if IsHolday equals zero, accumulate DaywisePlan into the total. If IsHolday equals one, accumulate the value of DaywisePlan on the next row in date order where IsHolday equals zero

| Date | DaywisePlan | IsHoliday | ExpectedOutput |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/1/2022 | 34 | 1 | 34 |
| 7/2/2022 | 34 | 1 | 34 |
| 7/3/2022 | 34 | 0 | 34 |
| 7/4/2022 | 34 | 0 | 68 |
| 7/5/2022 | 34 | 0 | 102 |
| 7/6/2022 | 34 | 0 | 136 |
| 7/7/2022 | 34 | 1 | 136 |
| 7/8/2022 | 34 | 1 | 136 |
| 7/9/2022 | 34 | 0 | 170 |
| 7/10/2022 | 34 | 0 | 204 |
| 7/11/2022 | 34 | 1 | 204 |
| 7/12/2022 | 34 | 0 | 238 |

Comment: what have you tried so far?m also should be the first two lines not have the expected result of 0 as they are both holidays?

Comment: Ya .. It should be zero.. I have updated it... If it is normal cummulative i can do it... But the problem what i am facing... If it has two holidays continuously in between then lag function wont work.

Comment: So why are the first 2 rows `34` and not `0`?

Comment: thats the requirement sir.. its like plan... it cannot be zero

Comment: Can you show us the SQL you have so far? Then we can help you to modify it.

Comment: Do where does the 34 come from, asthe first day is a holiday, so the sum of nothing is nothing... You aren't clear on your requirements here. You need to [edit] your question to actually give the full logic.

Comment: *"thats the requirement sir..*" I don't recall saying I prefer to be referenced as "sir" or that identify as male; please don't assume genders here. The ToS asks you to use gender neutral language unless someone asks you otherwise.

Comment: Yes allmhuran..

Comment: You could accumulate `DaywisePlan * (1 - IsHoliday)`, and then choose the maximum of that sum and the value of DayWisePlan for the first date.

Comment: You have edited the values in your table such that the expected output is no longer described by the logic I proposed.

Comment: The values haven't changed since [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73182515/2) @allmhuran .

Comment: I didnt edit the values. I just edited the logic description

Comment: The original data (being the data upon which I proposed the logic) had the value 68 (not 34) as the expected output for the third row, with the additional 34 also accumulated into all subsequent rows.

Comment: That change was done before your comment though, @allmhuran . Some 15 minutes beforehand. The OP made no change to the values after your proposed logic.

Comment: @Larnu I did not refresh the OP's data while authoring my comment. My logic describes the original data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in one Query id´ can't think of, but use a CTE , it is quite easy using  The window Function `SUM` and `FIRST_VALUE`

if you have more month and want to have a SUM for all month sereately, you need to `PARTITION` both window function mothwise

> ```
> WITH CTE AS
> (SELECT
>     [Date], [DaywisePlan], [IsHoliday],
>     FIRST_VALUE([DaywisePlan]) OVER(PARTITION BY [IsHoliday] ORDER By [Date]) [First],
>     SUM(CASE WHEN [IsHoliday] = 0 THEN [DaywisePlan] ELSe 0 END) OVER(ORDER By [Date]) as [Sum]
> FROM tab1)
> SELECT [Date], [DaywisePlan], [IsHoliday]
> ,CASE WHEN [Sum] = 0 AND [IsHoliday] = 1 THEN [Sum]+ [first] ELSe [Sum] END as [Sum] FROM CTE
> ```

> ```
> Date                    | DaywisePlan | IsHoliday | Sum
> :---------------------- | ----------: | --------: | --:
> 2022-07-01 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         1 |  34
> 2022-07-02 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         1 |  34
> 2022-07-03 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         0 |  34
> 2022-07-04 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         0 |  68
> 2022-07-05 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         0 | 102
> 2022-07-06 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         0 | 136
> 2022-07-07 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         1 | 136
> 2022-07-08 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         1 | 136
> 2022-07-09 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         0 | 170
> 2022-07-10 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         0 | 204
> 2022-07-11 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         1 | 204
> 2022-07-12 02:00:00.000 |          34 |         0 | 238
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a89684721d603219ce0c301b6c67e57)*

Comment: Unfortunately the expected results have been edited since originally posted.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments I proposed logic based on the first version of your expected results.

The expected results in the question as currently posed do not match that logic. Instead they seem to match this logic:

> Do not accumulate DaywisePlan until arriving at the first row in order of date ascending where IsHolday equals zero. For that row and all subsequent rows, if IsHolday equals zero, accumulate DaywisePlan into the total.

You have also used an ambiguous date format which I infer (given the nature of your question) to be 'month/day/year', but could also be valid 'day/month/year' values. Here it happens to be the caes that the interpretation makes no difference to the ordering, but you should make it a habit of using non-ambiguous date formats like 'yyyyMMdd'.

In any case, here is a query which will produce the original expected results, and another query which will produce the new expected results. I have used similar CTE's for both to make the logic (and the difference between them) a little easier to read.

```sql
create table #mytable
(
   [Date]         date primary key,
   DaywisePlan    int,
   IsHoliday      bit,
   ExpectedOutput int
);

set dateformat mdy;

-- original dataset

insert #mytable values
('7/1/2022',   34,   1,  34 ),
('7/2/2022',   34,   1,  34 ),
('7/3/2022',   34,   0,  68 ),
('7/4/2022',   34,   0,  102 ),
('7/5/2022',   34,   0,  136 ),
('7/6/2022',   34,   0,  170 ),
('7/7/2022',   34,   1,  170 ),
('7/8/2022',   34,   1,  170 ),
('7/9/2022',   34,   0,  204 ),
('7/10/2022',  34,   0,  238 ),
('7/11/2022',  34,   1,  238 ),
('7/12/2022',  34,   0,  272 );

-- logic producing original dataset

with working as
(
   select      [date],
               DaywisePlan,
               IsHoliday,
               ExpectedOutput,
               FullAccum      =  sum(DayWisePlan) 
                                 over (order by [date] rows unbounded preceding),
               HoldayAccum    =  sum
                                 (
                                    iif(isHoliday = 1 and [date] != t.mindate, DayWisePlan, 0)
                                 ) over (order by [date] rows unbounded preceding)
   from        #mytable
   cross join (select min([date]) from #myTable) t(mindate)
)
select   [date], 
         daywiseplan, 
         isholiday, 
         expectedoutput,  
         CalculatedOutput = FullAccum - HoldayAccum
from     working;

-- edited dataset

delete from #mytable;

insert #mytable values
('7/1/2022',   34,   1,   34  ),
('7/2/2022',   34,   1,   34  ),
('7/3/2022',   34,   0,   34  ),
('7/4/2022',   34,   0,   68  ),
('7/5/2022',   34,   0,   102 ),
('7/6/2022',   34,   0,   136 ),
('7/7/2022',   34,   1,   136 ),
('7/8/2022',   34,   1,   136 ),
('7/9/2022',   34,   0,   170 ),
('7/10/2022',  34,   0,   204 ),
('7/11/2022',  34,   1,   204 ),
('7/12/2022',  34,   0,   238 );

-- logic to produce edited dataset
with working as
(
   select      [date],
               DaywisePlan,
               IsHoliday,
               ExpectedOutput,
               firstNonHoliday   = (select min([date]) from #myTable where IsHoliday = 0),
               FullAccum         =  sum(DayWisePlan) 
                                    over (order by [date] rows unbounded preceding),
               HoldayAccum       =  sum
                                    (
                                       iif(isHoliday = 1, DayWisePlan, 0)
                                    ) over (order by [date] rows unbounded preceding)
   from        #mytable
)
select   [date], 
         daywiseplan, 
         isholiday, 
         expectedoutput,  
         CalculatedOutput = iif([date] < firstNonHoliday, daywiseplan, FullAccum - HoldayAccum)
from     working;
```

If you just mean to say "ignore any holidays after the first non-holiday" then the logic can be significantly simplified (keeping the CTE for comparative purposes):

```sql
with working as
(
   select      [date],
               DaywisePlan,
               IsHoliday,
               ExpectedOutput,
               firstNonHoliday   = (select min([date]) from #myTable where IsHoliday = 0),
               FullAccum         = sum(iif(isHoliday = 0, DayWisePlan, 0)) 
                                   over(order by date rows unbounded preceding)
   from        #mytable  
   
)
select   [date], 
         daywiseplan, 
         isholiday, 
         expectedoutput,  
         CalculatedOutput = iif([date] <= firstNonHoliday, dayWisePlan, fullaccum)
from     working;
```